# NSURL returning nil if string passed has arabic words and spaces

Tags: nsurl

Actually Iam trying to create NSUrl From string which comprises of english as well as arabic words with spaces.but the NSURl returns null after passing this to nsurl. what should i do to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

you should do like this:
second line is important.

```
NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.ModelAirplane.ir/هاشم"];

urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
NSLog(@"%@",url.description);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this in **Swift 2.0**

```
let  = "http://example.ir/اسم-عربي"
let safeURL = urlStr.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32703510/1599713)