# How to encode a URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode

This is my `URL`.

The problem is, that the `address` field is not being appended to `urlpath`.

Does anyone know why that is?

```
var address:string
address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"
let urlpath = NSString(format: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+"\(address)")
```

Comment: `let urlpath =  "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(address)")` is enough i guess

Comment: "Some string" + "\\(aString)" is overkill... Simply use "Some string \\(aString)"

Comment: Or just "some string" + aString

Comment: We can use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters ` method. **You can find more details in this ANSWER: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44643893/4061501**

Answer (score 261):

#### Swift 4.2

```
var urlString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

#### Swift 3.0

```
var address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"
let escapedAddress = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
let urlpath = String(format: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(escapedAddress)")
```

Use [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:):

```
var escapedAddress = address.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

---

<del>Use [`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:)</del> *Deprecated in iOS 9 and OS X v10.11*

```
var address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"
var escapedAddress = address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let urlpath = NSString(format: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(escapedAddress)")
```

Comment: You might want to modify that character set so that if `+` or `&` appear in the `address` value, that they get percent escaped. Unfortunately, `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` will let those pass unescaped, which will alter the value parsed by the server.

Comment: Rob is right, `var escapedAddress = address.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
` is still blind to **&** and **+** character

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: is deprecated on iOS 9, better use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters

Comment: How do you modify the character set to include + and &? Why in the world does it not include them?

Comment: `let s = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy()
s.addCharactersInString("+&")`

Comment: let unreserved = "-._~/?"
                                    let allowed = NSMutableCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
                                    allowed.addCharactersInString(unreserved) you can read more from http://useyourloaf.com/blog/how-to-percent-encode-a-url-string/

Comment: It only works for me if I remove them from the NSCharacterSet:  let s = NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy()  as! NSMutableCharacterSet; s.removeCharactersInString("+&"); let sSafe : String! = s.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(s)

Comment: It worked perfectly for me using NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()

Comment: @BryanChen - I think you meant `removeCharactersInString`, not `addCharactersInString`.

Comment: @gonglong - You don't want to use `alphanumericCharacterSet` because that's actually a huge character set that includes lots of international characters, which I'm sure you didn't intend.

Comment: @JeremyHicks - You asked why `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` allows `&` and `+` to pass unescaped. It does that because, technically, those characters _are_ allowed to be in the "query" portion of the URI, but it's just that they serve special purposes within `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests. So, my beef with Apple is not necessarily that they included them within `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` (because, within a strict reading of the RFCs, Apple is correct), but that they don't have a desperately needed character set that we can use for keys and values _within_ the `x-www-form-urlencoded` query.

Comment: urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

Answer (score 84):

If it's possible that the value that you're adding to your URL can have reserved characters (as defined by section 2 of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3986)), you might have to refine your percent-escaping. Notably, while `&` and `+` are valid characters in a URL, they're not valid within a URL query parameter value (because `&` is used as delimiter between query parameters which would prematurely terminate your value, and `+` is translated to a space character). Unfortunately, the standard percent-escaping leaves those delimiters unescaped.

Thus, you might want to percent escape all characters that are not within RFC 3986's list of unreserved characters:

> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
>      purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
>      letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
>      unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

Later, in section 3.4, the RFC further contemplates adding `?` and `/` to the list of allowed characters within a query:

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
>      within the query component.  Beware that some older, erroneous
>      implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as
>      the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently
>      because they fail to distinguish query data from path data when
>      looking for hierarchical separators. However, as query components
>      are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
>      "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to
>      another URI, it is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-
>      encoding those characters.

Nowadays, you'd generally use `URLComponents` to percent escape the query value:

```
var address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"
var components = URLComponents(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json")!
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "address", value: address)]
let url = components.url!
```

---

By the way, while it's not contemplated in the aforementioned RFC, [section 5.2, URL-encoded form data](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-serializing), of the W3C HTML spec says that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests should also replace space characters with `+` characters (and includes the asterisk in the characters that should not be escaped). And, unfortunately, `URLComponents` won't properly percent escape this, so Apple advises that you manually percent escape it before retrieving the `url` property of the `URLComponents` object:

```
// configure `components` as shown above, and then:

components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
let url = components.url!
```

For Swift 2 rendition, where I manually do all of this percent escaping myself, see the [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24888789/7).

Comment: This is more advanced and bulletproof response.

Comment: Are you missing a ~ in the last example? e.g. characterSet.addCharactersInString("-._~* ")

Comment: No, that's my point. RFC3986 and the W3C HTML spec are not entirely consistent. The W3C HTML spec explicitly says "If the byte is in the range 0x2A (`*`), 0x2D (`-`), 0x2E (`.`), 0x30 to 0x39 (`0`-`9`), 0x41 to 0x5A (`A`-`Z`), 0x5F (`_`), 0x61 to 0x7A (`a`-`z`), leave the byte as is, [otherwise percent escape]." The W3C spec doesn't contemplate `~`. In practice, it probably doesn't really matter that much (most web servers will accept it unescaped).

Comment: +1 for the x-www-form-urlencoded part.  Every other answer I've seen out there fails to work for that situation.

Comment: This is exactly what I need for sending + in the query variable. Thanks for the documentation as well.

Comment: There're 103806 characters in the `alphanumericCharacterSet` (almost entire Unicode), this might be too slow. See my answer for a more lightweight method.

Comment: You are correct that we really should use a character set that is more strictly in conformance with the RFC. I've revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: With the last example, I believe `+` is included in `URLQueryParameterAllowedCharacterSet`, so you are not encoding the `+` characters (before converting the spaces to `+`s). You need to add a line: `allowedCharacters.removeCharactersInString("+")` which will encode the actual instances of `+`.

Comment: @DanielTull - No, I suspect you are confusing my custom `URLQueryParameterAllowedCharacterSet` (which does not include `+`) with the system method, `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` (which does).

Answer (score 66):

**Swift 3:**

```
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

Comment: totally awesome answer, thanks.  To help for googlers, this replaces the old style ... **withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed()**

Comment: or better yet: `originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` :)

Comment: Work for me too. Thanks for that! :D

Answer (score 35):

**Swift 2.0**

```
let needsLove = "string needin some URL love"
let safeURL = needsLove.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

[*Helpful Progamming Tips and Hacks*](https://gist.github.com/chess92/72b082cd17bbe8cab78e)

Answer (score 16):

`URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` should not be used for URL encoding of query parameters because this charset includes `&`, `?`, `/` etc. which serve as delimiters in a URL query, e.g.

```
/?paramname=paramvalue&paramname=paramvalue
```

These characters are allowed in URL queries as a whole but not in parameter values.

[RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) specifically talks about **unreserved** characters, which are different from allowed:

> 2.3.  Unreserved Characters
>
> Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
> purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
> letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.
>
> ```
>   unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```

Accordingly:

```
extension String {
    var URLEncoded:String {

        let unreservedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~"
        let unreservedCharsSet: CharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: unreservedChars)
        let encodedString = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: unreservedCharsSet)!
        return encodedString
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't make a call to `alphanumericCharacterSet` because of the enormous size of the charset it returns (103806 characters). And in view of how many Unicode characters `alphanumericCharacterSet` allows for, using it for the purpose of URL encoding would be simply erroneous.

Usage:

```
let URLEncodedString = myString.URLEncoded
```

Comment: Nice answer. But you posted it twice, it would have been better to flag one of the questions as duplicate.

Comment: Did I say otherwise? I even said "nice answer". :/ What I'm saying is *don't post the same answer multiple times*, that's all.

Comment: There are so many wrong answers around this topic that I felt that more people should see this answer before they start adding bugs into their code. But ok, gonna stick to this question exclusively now.

Comment: This is not true, you should use `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` for encoding you queries. But not you totally query! You should encode each value of the total query with `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` so it should work.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.1**

Create a "Character Set" based on the option you want (urlQueryAllowed). Then remove the additional characters you do not want (+&). Then pass that character set to "addingPercentEncoding".

```
var address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"
var queryCharSet = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")
let escapedAddress = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet)!
let urlpath = String(format: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\(escapedAddress)")
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing too. I'd think they need a urlQueryValueAllowed too (though I supposed technically + is *allowed* as part of a query value too).

Answer (score 7):

> XCODE 8, SWIFT 3.0

***From grokswift***

*Creating URLs from strings is a minefield for bugs. Just miss a single / or accidentally URL encode the ? in a query and your API call will fail and your app won’t have any data to display (or even crash if you didn’t anticipate that possibility). **Since iOS 8 there’s a better way to build URLs using `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItems`.***

```
func createURLWithComponents() -> URL? {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "http"
    urlComponents.host = "maps.googleapis.com"
    urlComponents.path = "/maps/api/geocode/json"

    let addressQuery = URLQueryItem(name: "address", value: "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India")
    urlComponents.queryItems = [addressQuery]

    return urlComponents.url
}
```

*Below is the code to access url using `guard` statement.*

```
guard let url = createURLWithComponents() else {
            print("invalid URL")
            return nil
      }
      print(url)
```

***Output:***

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=American%20Tourister,%20Abids%20Road,%20Bogulkunta,%20Hyderabad,%20Andhra%20Pradesh,%20India
```

Read More: [Building URLs With NSURLComponents and NSURLQueryItems](https://grokswift.com/building-urls/)

Comment: Swift 3.0 urlAsString = urlAsString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!

Answer (score 5):

Just completing Desmond Hume's answer to extend the String class for a **RFC 3986 unreserved characters** valid encoding function (needed if you are encoding query FORM parameters):

### Swift 3

```
extension String {

    var RFC3986UnreservedEncoded:String {
        let unreservedChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~"
        let unreservedCharsSet: CharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: unreservedChars)
        let encodedString: String = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: unreservedCharsSet)!
        return encodedString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated for Swift 3:

```
var escapedAddress = address.addingPercentEncoding(
    withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Mac OS 10.9 Maverics and iOS 7 `NSURLComponents` has been introduced which handles the encoding of the different URL parts in a pretty convenient way.

> The NSURLComponents class is a class that is designed to parse URLs
>   based on RFC 3986 and to construct URLs from their constituent parts.
>   Its behavior differs subtly from the NSURL class, which conforms to
>   older RFCs. However, you can easily obtain an NSURL object based on
>   the contents of a URL components object or vice versa.

```
let address = "American Tourister, Abids Road, Bogulkunta, Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India"

let components = NSURLComponents(string: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json")!
// create a query item key=value
let queryItem = NSURLQueryItem(name: "address", value: address)
// add the query item to the URL, NSURLComponents takes care of adding the question mark.
components.queryItems = [queryItem]
// get the properly percent encoded string
let urlpath = components.string!
print(urlpath)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get my google query working again! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Bryan Chen's answer above:

Just incase anyone else is getting something similar with Alamofire:

> error: Alamofire was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave
>   oddly; variables may not be available.

It's not a very descriptive error. I was getting that error when constructing a URL for google geo services. I was appending a street address to the end of the URL WITHOUT encoding the street address itself first. 
I was able to fix it using Bryan Chen's solution:

```
var streetAdress = "123 fake street, new york, ny"
var escapedStreetAddress = streetAddress.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
let url = "\(self.baseUrl)&address=\(escapedAddress!)"
```

That fixed it for me! It didnt like that the address had spaces and commas, etc.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to encode my parameters with ISO-8859-1, so the addingPercentEncoding() method doesn't work for me.
I made a solution my self in Swift 4:

```
extension String {

  // Url percent encoding according to RFC3986 specifications
  // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1
  func urlPercentEncoded(withAllowedCharacters allowedCharacters: 
    CharacterSet, encoding: String.Encoding) -> String {
    var returnStr = ""

    // Compute each char seperatly
    for char in self {
      let charStr = String(char)
      let charScalar = charStr.unicodeScalars[charStr.unicodeScalars.startIndex]
      if allowedCharacters.contains(charScalar) == false,
        let bytesOfChar = charStr.data(using: encoding) {
        // Get the hexStr of every notAllowed-char-byte and put a % infront of it, append the result to the returnString
        for byte in bytesOfChar {
          returnStr += "%" + String(format: "%02hhX", byte as CVarArg)
        }
      } else {
        returnStr += charStr
      }
    }

    return returnStr
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
"aouäöü!".urlPercentEncoded(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed,
                                         encoding: .isoLatin1) 
// Results in -> "aou%E4%F6%FC!"
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case where the last component was non latin characters I did the following in `Swift 2.2`:

```
extension String {
 func encodeUTF8() -> String? {
//If I can create an NSURL out of the string nothing is wrong with it
if let _ = NSURL(string: self) {

    return self
}

//Get the last component from the string this will return subSequence
let optionalLastComponent = self.characters.split { $0 == "/" }.last


if let lastComponent = optionalLastComponent {

    //Get the string from the sub sequence by mapping the characters to [String] then reduce the array to String
    let lastComponentAsString = lastComponent.map { String($0) }.reduce("", combine: +)


    //Get the range of the last component
    if let rangeOfLastComponent = self.rangeOfString(lastComponentAsString) {
        //Get the string without its last component
        let stringWithoutLastComponent = self.substringToIndex(rangeOfLastComponent.startIndex)


        //Encode the last component
        if let lastComponentEncoded = lastComponentAsString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()) {


        //Finally append the original string (without its last component) to the encoded part (encoded last component)
        let encodedString = stringWithoutLastComponent + lastComponentEncoded

            //Return the string (original string/encoded string)
            return encodedString
        }
    }
}

return nil;
}
}
```