# Pass Parameter in WebService in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift and I don't know how to send parameters to server using Swift.
In Objective-C we can do this by using `"%@"` as the placeholder.
But what should be done in case of Swift, suppose I have a login webservice which requires email and password.

Now I want to know is that how will i send the `logintextfield` and `passwordtextfield` text to the server, such as,

```
var bodyData = "email=logintextfield.text&password=passwordtextfield.text"
```

Answer (score 10):

When creating a HTTP request that includes user input, one should generally percent escape it in case there are any reserved characters in the user's input, thus:

```
let login    = logintextfield.text?.addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue() ?? ""
let password = passwordtextfield.text?.addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue() ?? ""
let bodyData = "email=\(login)&password=\(password)"
```

Note, you'd really want to check to see if `login` and `password` were `nil` or not. Anyway, the percent-escaping is done as follows:

```
extension String {

    /// Percent escapes values to be added to a URL query as specified in RFC 3986
    ///
    /// This percent-escapes all characters besides the alphanumeric character set and "-", ".", "_", and "~".
    ///
    /// http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt
    ///
    /// :returns: Returns percent-escaped string.

    func addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue() -> String? {
        let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~")

        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacters)
    }

}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888789/1271826) for another rendition of this extension.

---

If you wanted to see a demonstration of the use of the above, imagine the following request:

```
let keyData = "AIzaSyCRLa4LQZWNQBcjCYcIVYA45i9i8zfClqc"
let sensorInformation = false
let types = "building"
let radius = 1000000
let locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:40.748716, longitude: -73.985643)
let name = "Empire State Building, New York, NY"
let floors = 102
let now = Date()

let params:[String: Any] = [
    "key" : keyData,
    "sensor" : sensorInformation,
    "typesData" : types,
    "radius" : radius,
    "location" : locationCoordinate,
    "name" : name,
    "floors" : floors,
    "when" : now,
    "pi" : M_PI]

let url = URL(string: "http://some.web.site.com/inquiry")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = params.dataFromHttpParameters()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard data != nil && error == nil else {
        print("error submitting request: \(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
        print("response was not 200: \(response)")
        return
    }

    // handle the data of the successful response here
}
task.resume()
```

I'm including lots of parameters that were not included in your example, but simply as a way of illustrating the routine's handling of a diverse array of parameter types.

Incidentally, the above uses my `datafromHttpParameters` function:

```
extension Dictionary {

    /// This creates a String representation of the supplied value.
    ///
    /// This converts NSDate objects to a RFC3339 formatted string, booleans to "true" or "false",
    /// and otherwise returns the default string representation.
    ///
    /// - parameter value: The value to be converted to a string
    ///
    /// - returns:         String representation

    private func httpStringRepresentation(_ value: Any) -> String {
        switch value {
        case let date as Date:
            return date.rfc3339String()
        case let coordinate as CLLocationCoordinate2D:
            return "\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)"
        case let boolean as Bool:
            return boolean ? "true" : "false"
        default:
            return "\(value)"
        }
    }

    /// Build `Data` representation of HTTP parameter dictionary of keys and objects
    ///
    /// This percent escapes in compliance with RFC 3986
    ///
    /// http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt
    ///
    /// :returns: String representation in the form of key1=value1&key2=value2 where the keys and values are percent escaped

    func dataFromHttpParameters() -> Data {
        let parameterArray = self.map { (key, value) -> String in
            let percentEscapedKey = (key as! String).addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue()!
            let percentEscapedValue = httpStringRepresentation(value).addingPercentEncodingForURLQueryValue()!
            return "\(percentEscapedKey)=\(percentEscapedValue)"
        }

        return parameterArray.joined(separator: "&").data(using: .utf8)!
    }

}
```

Here, because I'm dealing with an array of parameter strings, I use the `join` function to concatenate them separated by `&`, but the idea the same.

Feel free to customize that function to handle whatever data types you may be passing into it (e.g. I don't generally have `CLLocationCoordinate2D` in there, but your example included one, so I wanted to show what it might look like). But the key is that if you're supplying any fields that include user input, make sure to percent-escape it.

FYI, this is my `rfc3339String` function which is used above. (Clearly, if you don't need to transmit dates, you don't need this, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness for a more generalized solution.)

```
extension Date {

    /// Get RFC 3339/ISO 8601 string representation of the date.
    ///
    /// For more information, see:
    ///
    /// https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html
    ///
    /// - returns: Return RFC 3339 representation of date string

    func rfc3339String() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

To see Swift 2 rendition, see [previous rendition](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25154803/14) of this answer.

Comment: Yes you helped me out..!! It Works for me..:)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by passing the required parameter in the service like this,

```
var urlPath = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key=AIzaSyCRLa4LQZWNQBcjCYcIVYA45i9i8zfClqc&sensor=false&types=restaurant&radius=100000&location=\(locationCoord)")
```

Here `urlPath` is the url containing web service and `locationCoord` (as last parameter) is the run time value for the location parameter for the web service. The parameter key, sensor, radius and types are fixed.

Comment: Obviously, though, you would never add a userid or password, as in your question, to a URL, because that's not very secure. Those would always go in the body of the request.

Comment: @Rob you mean that while sending userid or password to the server I will have to send them in the body of the request?? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, that's generally advised because URLs aren't terribly secure (you might find them squirreled away in web logs on your server or elsewhere). Generally people advise that secure information be sent in the body of a `POST` request, not in the URL itself. I inferred from your `bodyData` variable name that you were already including these HTTP request parameters in the body of the request, but was unclear on the basis of this answer, which included them in the URL.

Comment: @Rob I am getting your point. I write the following code,let keyData   = "AIzaSyCRLa4LQZWNQBcjCYcIVYA45i9i8zfClqc"
        let sensorData = "false"
        let typesData = "restaurant"
        let radiusData = "1000000"
        let coored = locationCoord
        let bodyData = "key="+keyData+"&sensor="+sensorData+"&types="+typesData+"&radius="+radiusDaat+"&location="+coored
println("complete data is \(bodyData)"), Here coored is the lat and long concatenated. Then I paas the body Data like, request.HTTPBody = bodyData. Is this correct? Can you give me some sample code. Thanks.

Comment: See my revised answer which includes example (probably more than you need, but illustrative of the concepts).

Answer (score 0):

I am calling the json on login button click

```
@IBAction func loginClicked(sender : AnyObject){

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: kLoginURL)) // Here, kLogin contains the Login API.

  var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.criteriaDic(), options: nil, error: &err) // This Line fills the web service with required parameters.
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
     //   println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")       
    var err1: NSError?
    var json2 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(strData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err1 ) as NSDictionary

    println("json2 :\(json2)")

    if(err) {
        println(err!.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        var success = json2["success"] as? Int
        println("Succes: \(success)")
    }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Here, I have made a seperate dictionary for the parameters.

```
var params = ["format":"json", "MobileType":"IOS","MIN":"f8d16d98ad12acdbbe1de647414495ec","UserName":emailTxtField.text,"PWD":passwordTxtField.text,"SigninVia":"SH"]as NSDictionary
     return params
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above I ended up with this, to get a token within a Set-Cookie element.

Where the URLResponse was

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17403ef20> { URL: http://bla.co.uk//auth/authenticate?email=bob@isp.eu&password=xcode } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 17 Feb 2017 10:51:41 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = nginx;
    "Set-Cookie" = "token=Cu4CmOaverylongstring0mCu4CmOpBGg; expires=Fri, 17-Feb-2017 20:51:41 GMT; Max-Age=36000; path=auth; httponly";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19, PleskLin";
} }



func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

    if statusCode == 200 {
        let keyValues = httpResponse.allHeaderFields.map { (String(describing: $0.key).lowercased(), String(describing: $0.value)) }

        // Now filter the array, searching for your header-key, also lowercased
        if let myHeaderValue = keyValues.filter({ $0.0 == "Set-Cookie".lowercased() }).first {
            print(myHeaderValue.1)
            let cookies = myHeaderValue.1
            let cookieDict = cookies.components(separatedBy: ";")
            print("\(cookieDict)")
            let tokenEntryParameter = cookieDict.filter({$0 .contains("token")})
            let tokenEntry = tokenEntryParameter.first
            token = (tokenEntry?.components(separatedBy: "=").last)!
        }
    }
}
```