# my swift app fails to return a dictionary value

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

The method fails to return a value got from a GET request where variable `res` can be printed in the task section, but fails to return it in the end.

```
func lookUpTheWord(word:String) -> NSDictionary {
    var res = NSDictionary()
    let urlString = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word
    if let url = NSURL(string:urlString) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("this is a key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("\(error)")
                return
            }
            res = self.toJson(data!)
            print(res) //it works here
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    return res //res becomes nil
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How do I return a value within an asynchronous urlsession function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081062/swift-how-do-i-return-a-value-within-an-asynchronous-urlsession-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're returning the variable res before it has been assigned. You'll notice that the `res` that isn't nil is printed after the one that is after it. This is because the HTTP request doesn't happen instantly - code after it is executed before it is finished, therefore it is called "asynchronous".

If you want to use the variable acquired in the HTTP request, use a closure as a parameter in your function and call it when the request is finished. Example:

```
func lookUpTheWord(word:String, completion: (NSDictionary->Void)) {
    var res = NSDictionary()
    let urlString = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/" + word
    if let url = NSURL(string:urlString) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("this is a key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Mashape-Key")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                res = self.toJson(data!)
                completion(res)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
lookUpTheWord("word") { res in
    print(res)
}
```