# Swift 3: how to return values out of session.uploadTask

Tags: json, multithreading, swift3, nsurlsession

Please can you tell me how to return [data] out of a session.uploadTask in oder to make [data] available for multiple ViewControllers?

My classes:

```
class data {
  var name1: String = ""
  var name2: String = ""
  ...
}

class fetchData {
  var url: String = ""
  var body: String = ""
  ... 

 func getDataFromServer (apiParrameters,...) -> [data] {
    var dataArray = [data]()     
    session.uploadTask() {
    // fetching the [data
    ...
    // adding [data]
    ... dataArray.append(data(name1: name1String, name2: name2String)) ...

   //Where to retun(dataArray)? In session.uploadTask it is not possible/accespted
   /* in OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
        //return(dataArray) is not possible
        })*/
 }
 resume(uploadTask)
 //return(dataArray) at this point results in an empty dataArray


 }
}
```

Comment: Have done research, for sure. Otherwise I would nit ask...Can you provide a link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: How do I return a value within an asynchronous urlsession function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081062/swift-how-do-i-return-a-value-within-an-asynchronous-urlsession-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion handler to call when the load request is complete. This handler is executed on the delegate queue.This completion handler takes the following parameters:

**data**
The data returned by the server.
**response**
An object that provides response metadata, such as HTTP headers and status code. If you are making an HTTP or HTTPS request, the returned object is actually an HTTPURLResponse object.
**error**
An error object that indicates why the request failed, or nil if the request was successful.

Comment: did not understand completely:-( can you give me a code example how to return my dataArray?

Comment: Any further help? I am stucked :-(

Comment: Have built a completion handler. Thx