# Swift: Get value from completion handler

Tags: swift

New to Swift -- apologies. Suppose `fetchString(@escaping completion: (String) -> Void)`.

How can I store the closure value `response` in `str`?

```
var str: String  // suppose this is initialized
API.fetchString() { response in
    str = response // or something similar like append
}
return str
```

Comment: closure/block is executed asynchronously, as it is a API call, but return statement will be executed synchronously hence str value will be returned even before `closure` could execute, hence you feel like str is not updated,

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27081062/1187415 or these related Q&As: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+return+from+asynchronous

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware these calls weren't on the main thread.