# POST values are being automatically filtered based on their type?

Tags: java, swift, authentication, xampp

Server backend is written in PHP, I am doing the iOS App in Swift, a friend is doing the Android Version in Java. Problem we both occur: When trying to develop the login for each respective app, when sending mail / password the POST data won't reach the server.

Example: "myUser@myMail.net" and "password" are sent to our server backend from either the iOS or the Android app. When sending that exact data, nothing will reach the server, resulting in an empty array output if the FIRST line of code in our app.php is `var_dump($_POST);`. However if I change "myUser@myMail.net" to "myUser@myMail.n" the address is longer valid and the POST data arrives at my server, without changing any code whatsoever. Now my API just tells me that there is no user for the given mail / password combination. If I change the data sent back to the .net variant, the POST data is lost again resulting in an empty array output again.

There is no code to show here, simply a normal `var_dump($_POST);` at the very first line of code in our PHP backend.

We are using normal XAMPP. This problem occurs when using XAMPP on either windows or Mac, letting the iOS app run on either the simulator or an actual device. It occurs when either letting it connect to "localhost" or the concrete fix IP of our server.

What the hell is going on here? I am completely clueless.

Comment: Are you testing on a device or via the simulator?

Comment: As i wrote: both. It happens on the simulator to localhost, the simulator to a concrete IP, the device to a concrete IP. For both the iOS and the Java version..

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the actual server as it occurs with both devices. I suggest you test if the issue arises while sending the request via [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop), or something similar. If the issue proceeds to happen, its definitely something with the actual server code.

Comment: @Idris: Thanks for the link, didn't know about that app. Problem here is: This happens for both, either myself on my XAMPP installation or my friend's machine with his XAMPP installation... Also: Something as standard as sending a mail address shouldn't cause any problems?

Comment: As long as it's a string, there should be no problem. However if the issue continues to happen during the test with Postman, I recommend you check the server logs as that should give you a definitive reason as to why the issue occurs.

Comment: @Idris: Ok, i tried a bit now with Postman. Turns out the same is happing there, so it's definetely the server. I am also using the code from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203708/post-request-in-swift-with-key-value-pairs which should be ok. I checked for error logs in my apache, but there is no interesting message logged that could be the cause of this. I am still getting array(0) when trying to sent the mailaddress via POST.

Comment: Check the PHP logs, not the Apache logs.

Comment: @Idris: Also nothing in the php_error_log... Just nothing appears, no error occurs. Server is running fine but "swallowing" the $_POST data, if it is a valid mail address..