# Swift Send Email with MailGun

Tags: swift, api, swift2, mailgun

**Problem**

I would like to use the [MailGun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#how-to-start-sending-email) service to send emails from a pure Swift app.

**Research So Far**

As I understand it, [there are two methods to send an email](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-smtp) via MailGun. One is to email MailGun with the emails, and MailGun will redirect it (See *Send via SMTP*). That will, as I understand it, not work, as iOS cannot programatically automatically send mail, and must use [methods that require user intervention](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-email-tutorial-ios8-swift). As such, I should use the API directly. As I understand it, I need to open a URL to do this, and so I should use some form of `NSURLSession`, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift)

**Code**

MailGun provides documentation for Python, which is as follows:

```
def send_simple_message():
return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox(Personal info).mailgun.org/messages",
    auth=("api", "key-(Personal info)"),
    data={"from": "Excited User <(Personal info)>",
          "to": ["bar@example.com", "(Personal info)"],
          "subject": "Hello",
          "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

with (Personal info) being substituted for keys/information/emails.

**Question**

How do I do that in Swift?

Thanks!

Comment: `requests.post` sends an HTTP POST request. You need to do the same.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thanks! Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that. If you post an answer with Swift code, I would be more than happy to accept your answer!

Comment: @rocket101 i added an answer for u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, the `auth` is being passed in the header.

You have to do a http post request, passing both the header and the body.

This is a working code:

```
func test() {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox(Personal info).mailgun.org/messages")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let data = "from: Excited User <(Personal info)>&to: [bar@example.com,(Personal info)]&subject:Hello&text:Testinggsome Mailgun awesomness!"
        request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        request.setValue("key-(Personal info)", forHTTPHeaderField: "api")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.URL!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }


        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I am using this code but am currently getting HTTP error code 401 - any ideas? My mailgun works fine using curl

Comment: @RJH could you please post a new question and I will try to find time to help you

Comment: posted here William - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387402/sending-email-with-swift-and-mailgun

Comment: u get a 401 error because u need to take out "key-" from the api key value. see my answer for how the construct the url correctly

Answer (score 3):

people are getting 400 or 401 errors because none of the other answers construct the url correctly. here is some code that works in swift 5 and iOS15:

```
func sendEmail() {
    // variablize our https path with API key, recipient and message text
    let mailgunAPIPath = "https://api:YOUR_API_KEY@api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN/messages?"
    let emailRecipient = "RECIPIENT@EMAIL.COM"
    let emailMessage = "Testing%20email%20sender%20variables"
    // Create a session and fill it with our request
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: mailgunAPIPath + "from=USER@YOUR_DOMAIN&to=\(emailRecipient)&subject=A%20New%20Test%21&text=\(emailMessage)")! as URL)
    
    // POST and report back with any errors and response codes
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        
        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.url!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`requests.post`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) sends an HTTP POST request, encoding key/value pairs as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to do the same.

- convert the set of key-value pairs into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as per [How to escape the HTTP params in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148100/how-to-escape-the-http-params-in-swift)
- compose the request using the resulting string for data & send it as per [iOS : http Post using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596114/ios-http-post-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to get the selected answer working, but to no avail.

Although I was finally able to get this working properly with a large HTTP response. I put the full path into Keys.plist so that I can upload my code to github and broke out some of the arguments into variables so I can have them programmatically set later down the road.

```
// Email the FBO with desired information
// Parse our Keys.plist so we can use our path
var keys: NSDictionary?

if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Keys", ofType: "plist") {
    keys = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let dict = keys {
    // variablize our https path with API key, recipient and message text
    let mailgunAPIPath = dict["mailgunAPIPath"] as? String
    let emailRecipient = "bar@foo.com"
    let emailMessage = "Testing%20email%20sender%20variables"

    // Create a session and fill it with our request
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: mailgunAPIPath! + "from=FBOGo%20Reservation%20%3Cscheduler@<my domain>.com%3E&to=reservations@<my domain>.com&to=\(emailRecipient)&subject=A%20New%20Reservation%21&text=\(emailMessage)")!)

    // POST and report back with any errors and response codes
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }

        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.URL!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The Mailgun Path is in Keys.plist as a string called mailgunAPIPath with the value:

```
https://API:key-<my key>@api.mailgun.net/v3/<my domain>.com/messages?
```

Hope this offers a solution to anyone else having issues with MailGun and wanting to avoid a 3rd party solution!

Comment: this doesn't work. it gives error 401. u need to take out "key-" in the mailgun path.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 answer:

```
    func test() {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox(Personal info).mailgun.org/messages")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let data = "from: Excited User <(Personal info)>&to: [bar@example.com,(Personal info)]&subject:Hello&text:Testinggsome Mailgun awesomness!"
        request.httpBody = data.data(using: .ascii)
        request.setValue("key-(Personal info)", forHTTPHeaderField: "api")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.url!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }


        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, when I tested my API key response return 401 and

2020-12-05 21:31:42.624789+0300 ExamMachine[6413:3043388] [connection] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C2] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for api.mailgun.net:443

Comment: u get a 401 error because u need to take out "key-" from the api key value. see my answer for how the construct the url correctly