# Submit textField from app to PHP

Tags: php, xcode, swift

In Xcode let's say I have a text field called textField and a submit button called buttonPressed.

What I need to do is type any information into textField, click the submit button and render a response from a php file which says "Thank you for submitting" or whatever. Just some response embedded in the php.

Started with the very basics:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http:...my url.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
```

I don't know the proper terminology to search for something like this. Happy to keep searching on my own just not sure what phrase to pop into Google! 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28259410/2227743), it's rather simple but will guide you through your first steps.