# Sending message to WhatsApp from your app using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

For one of my app, I wanted to share data to WhatsApp contacts. I tried few solutions overs the StackOverflow but couldn't get exact solution. After some trials could achieve what I was looking for, so sharing here for anyone's future reference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 var url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20Friends%2C%20Sharing%20some%20data%20here...%20!")

//Text which will be shared on WhatsApp is: "Hello Friends, Sharing some data here... !"

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().open(url as URL, options: [:]) { (success) in
                if success {
                    print("WhatsApp accessed successfully")
                } else {
                    print("Error accessing WhatsApp")
                }
            }
    }
```

Note: text needs to be URL encoded. You can get it using any of the open source tools over internet or using addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:) function in iOS.
e.g.

```
var urlString = "Hello Friends, Sharing some data here... !"
var urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
var url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(urlStringEncoded!)")
```

Comment: Hi@Pandurang Yachwad.   How Do i share a link can you SHOW  me a Demo. please.or is  there  a lenght of Url Which We can Share as I tried to Share www.Google.com Which Works But my URL is Too Long So I am Getting Blank In Text Area.

Comment: @AvinashMishra I don't think any limit for URL length. just check if that url works just directly in browser. sometime bad url causes the issue.

Comment: Working Fine in Browser not Here.

Comment: @AvinashMishra if you share you code, I can have look and let you know what's the issue

Comment: I have Post my Code in Answer please Check  and Sorry For New Question as i am not able to post New Question. Thats why i did This Sorry.

Comment: @AvinashMishra Sorry, couldn't respond earlier as I was traveling. You need to encode the URL, please use encoded url as below for your url:

Comment: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.proprofs.com%2Fquiz-school%2Fstory.php%3Ftitle%3Dpq-find-out-which-ice-age-character-you-are

Comment: not able to find the specific Line What would Be the Line Can You Please Sahre in SWIFT 3.Thanks

Comment: http%3A%2F%2Fwww.proprofs.com%2Fquiz-school%2Fstory.php%3Ftitle%3Dpq-find-out-which-ice-age-character-you-are

Comment: i mean to say which line of code will give me this kind of result.

Comment: I used http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ for encoding the URL. This is good for hard coded URL. if you need dynamic URL, you can use programatic solution as in this StackOverflow Q&A. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879659/how-to-encode-a-url-in-swift

Comment: @PandurangYachwad Can you please tell me how to open whatsapp from iOS app with a particular number. 

As you've shown here, it will open Whatsapp with a msg but I want to open Chat section of whatsapp with a particular number.

Comment: Is there any character limit?

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri I don’t think there is any limit for number of characters as far as they are in right format

Comment: @PandurangYachwad my message gets trimmed off from the between

Comment: For trimming issue is there any fixes @VaibhavJhaveri

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5**

[image: Add whatsapp in LSApplicationQuerySchemes(Info.plist)]

**Code**

```
let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\("Hello World")"
if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
      if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                 UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL)
             } 
             else {
                 print("please install watsapp")
             }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3.0

Try with this code for access watsapp in your application. Its working perfectly for me.

```
@IBAction func sendButtonAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let date = Date()
    let msg = "Hi my dear friends\(date)"
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"

    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
            } else {
                print("please install watsapp")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any character limit?

Comment: where you have mention the number on which i have to send the message????

Answer (score 6):

Addition to above solutions, starting from iOS 9, we need to add whatsapp to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in info.plist. After this only it worked for me.

[image: screen shot of solution]

Answer (score 2):

My code is Looking Like this

```
let encodeQuizStr = "Check Out The Quiz With link \n http://www.proprofs.com "

        let urlQuizStringEncoded = encodeQuizStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

        guard let whatsAppUrl = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text="+urlQuizStringEncoded!) else { return }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsAppUrl as URL) {

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                print(urlQuizStringEncoded!)
                UIApplication.shared.open(whatsAppUrl as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {

                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsAppUrl as URL)

            }
        }
        else{


            ProjectUtility.AlertWith(self, message: " What's App is Not Available.", Title: "Sorry")
        }
```

working fine But When I put This URL

```
("http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=pq-find-out-which-ice-age-character-you-are ")
```

Then Its Not Working Please Check Thanks.HelpWill Be Appriciated.

Comment: let urlString = "whatsapp://send?text=" + (self.modelForScreen?.deeplinkNarration ?? " ")
            
            let urlStringEncoded = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
            
            if let URL = URL(string: urlStringEncoded!), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }else{
                Utility.showToast("Whatsapp not installed.")
            }

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Please follow the below steps for sharing on WhatsApp through URL Schemes

1. Add this code in your app "info.plist"

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

[image]

2. For sharing text and URL

**Code**

```
    @IBAction func whatsappShareText(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    
        let message = "First Whatsapp Share & https://www.google.co.in"
        var queryCharSet = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        
        // if your text message contains special characters like **+ and &** then add this line
        queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")
        
        if let escapedString = message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet) {
            if let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString)") {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [: ], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    debugPrint("please install WhatsApp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

As per their FAQ, you should be using the universal links instead:

https://wa.me/1234567890

Reference: https://faq.whatsapp.com/563219570998715/?locale=en_US