# How to send message and link to WhatsApp in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, whatsapp

How to send a message and link to WhatsApp in Swift 3

I'm using this code:
  [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43513428/8255342)

Message errore to the console:

> ...failed for URL: "whatsapp://send?text=Check" - error: "This app is
>   not allowed to query for scheme whatsapp"

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending message to WhatsApp from your app using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042702/sending-message-to-whatsapp-from-your-app-using-swift)

Answer (score 17):

You should try this:

**Note:** You must have whatsapp app installed into your device.

**Swift 3**

```
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

@IBAction func whatsappShareText(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let originalString = "First Whatsapp Share"
    let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

    let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString!)")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func whatsappShareLink(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let originalString = "https://www.google.co.in"
    let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    let url  = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString!)")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Add this code in your app "info.plist"

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

Please follow the below steps for sharing on WhatsApp through URL Schemes

1. Add this code in your app "info.plist"

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

[image]

2. For sharing text and URL

   ```
    @IBAction func whatsappShareText(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let message = "First Whatsapp Share & https://www.google.co.in"
    var queryCharSet = NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed

    // if your text message contains special char like **+ and &** then add this line
    queryCharSet.remove(charactersIn: "+&")

    if let escapedString = message.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: queryCharSet) {
        if let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString)") {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL, options: [: ], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                debugPrint("please install WhatsApp")
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Happy Coding!