# Replacement for stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding in ios9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, encoding, deprecated

In iOS8 and prior I can use:

```
NSString *str = ...; // some URL
NSString *result = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

in iOS9 `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` has been replaced with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`:

```
NSString *str = ...; // some URL
NSCharacterSet *set = ???; // where to find set for NSUTF8StringEncoding?
NSString *result = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

and my question is: where to find needed `NSCharacterSet` (`NSUTF8StringEncoding`) for proper replacement of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The deprecation message says (emphasis mine):

> Use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(_:) instead, **which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding**, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.

So you only need to supply an adequate `NSCharacterSet` as argument. Luckily, for URLs there's a very handy class method called `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` that you can use like this:

```
let encodedHost = unencodedHost.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Update for *Swift 3* -- the method becomes the static property `urlHostAllowed`:

```
let encodedHost = unencodedHost.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

Be aware, though, that:

> This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string.

Comment: Also, I would strongly suggest using `NSURLComponents`, which can handle percent-encoding for you.

Comment: Any suggestions for what to use for the entire URL string?

Comment: @SkillM2 I think `NSURLComponents` (with each component percent-encoded with the corresponding `NSCharacterSet`) is the right way to go.

Comment: You should never, ever, never attempt to encode an entire URL string.  It can cause unexpected bugs, and in some cases, security holes.  The only guaranteed correct way to encode a URL is to do it one piece at a time.

Comment: how do you do this for swift 3?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan In Swift 3 it becomes `let encodedHost = unencodedHost.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)`

Answer (score 102):

For Objective-C：

```
NSString *str = ...; // some URL
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]; 
NSString *result = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

where to find set for NSUTF8StringEncoding?

There are predefined character sets for the six URL components and subcomponents which allow percent encoding. These character sets are passed to  `-stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` .

```
 // Predefined character sets for the six URL components and subcomponents which allow percent encoding. These character sets are passed to -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:.
@interface NSCharacterSet (NSURLUtilities)
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLUserAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLHostAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPathAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet;
@end
```

The deprecation message says (emphasis mine):

> Use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(_:) instead, **which always uses the recommended UTF-8 encoding**, and which encodes for a specific URL component or subcomponent since each URL component or subcomponent has different rules for what characters are valid.

So you only need to supply an adequate `NSCharacterSet` as argument. Luckily, for URLs there's a very handy class method called `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` that you can use like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet];
```

Be aware, though, that:

> This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string.

Comment: I love when Apple makes life easier. Thanks apple.

Comment: What is the meaning of "This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string." ?

Comment: URLHostAllowedCharacterSet was giving error "Unsupported URL", I used URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet and its working fine.

Comment: this does not work with + it will not encode it and it will be replaced by space on server side as by specification.

Answer (score 51):

`URLHostAllowedCharacterSet` is **NOT WORKING** FOR ME. I use `URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet` instead.

**OBJECTIVE -C**

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet];
NSString * encodedString = [@"url string" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

**SWIFT - 4**

```
"url string".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

The following are useful (inverted) character sets:

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

Comment: Thanks and same to you also

Comment: Worth noticing that none of these sets include `+`. So plus signs in the string will be messed up if passed on in query parameters - treated as space ` ` on the server side.

Comment: Actually, the `+` sign will be encoded to `%2B`. So no worries. It will work. @AsmoSoinio

Answer (score 22):

Objective-C

this code work for me :

```
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 4):

`Swift 2.2:`

```
extension String {
 func encodeUTF8() -> String? {
//If I can create an NSURL out of the string nothing is wrong with it
if let _ = NSURL(string: self) {

    return self
}

//Get the last component from the string this will return subSequence
let optionalLastComponent = self.characters.split { $0 == "/" }.last


if let lastComponent = optionalLastComponent {

    //Get the string from the sub sequence by mapping the characters to [String] then reduce the array to String
    let lastComponentAsString = lastComponent.map { String($0) }.reduce("", combine: +)


    //Get the range of the last component
    if let rangeOfLastComponent = self.rangeOfString(lastComponentAsString) {
        //Get the string without its last component
        let stringWithoutLastComponent = self.substringToIndex(rangeOfLastComponent.startIndex)


        //Encode the last component
        if let lastComponentEncoded = lastComponentAsString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()) {


        //Finally append the original string (without its last component) to the encoded part (encoded last component)
        let encodedString = stringWithoutLastComponent + lastComponentEncoded

            //Return the string (original string/encoded string)
            return encodedString
        }
    }
}

return nil;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.0

You can use `urlHostAllowed` characterSet.

> /// Returns the character set for characters allowed in a host URL subcomponent.

```
public static var urlHostAllowed: CharacterSet { get }

WebserviceCalls.getParamValueStringForURLFromDictionary(settingsDict as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the meaning of "This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string." ? – GeneCode Sep 1 '16 at 8:30

It means that you are not supposed to encode the `https://xpto.example.com/path/subpath` of the url, but only what goes after the `?`.

Supposed, because there are use-cases for doing it in cases like:

```
https://example.com?redirectme=xxxxx
```

Where `xxxxx` is a fully encoded URL.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer.
Taking into consideration this note

> This method is intended to percent-encode an URL component or subcomponent string, NOT an entire URL string.

the whole URL should not be encoded:

```
let param = "=color:green|\(latitude),\(longitude)&\("zoom=13&size=\(width)x\(height)")&sensor=true&key=\(staticMapKey)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) 
let url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers" + param!
```