# Unable to construct URL from String containing multiple anchor in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have received a URL string with double anchors, but I am unable to generate a `URL` object from that string.

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/help.html#details#moredetails") // returns nil
```

The URL is valid and we are able to open it in browser. The # in my url does not really act as an anchor, it actually opens a new page. 
Is there any way to create URL with multiple # in the url path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this little workaround that might solve your problem

```
let htmlFilePath = "https://www.example.com/help.html"
var url = URL(string: htmlFilePath)
url = URL(string: "#details", relativeTo: url)!
url = URL(string: "#moredetails", relativeTo: url)!
```

Comment: I tried this, its finally converting to "https://www.example.com/help.html#moredetails"

Comment: My bad. I don't know if you've came across this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658649/double-hashtag-in-openurl-crashes-the-app but it looks like this might be the cause why you can't initialize your URL

Answer (score 0):

There is an idea to replace the second, third, and so on anchor symbols `#`  with an escaped character sequence `%23`:

```
let stringUrl = "https://www.example.com/help.html#details#moredetails"
        
let hostWithAnchors = stringUrl.components(separatedBy: "#")
if hostWithAnchors.count > 2 {
    let hostWithPath = hostWithAnchors[0]
    let anchors = hostWithAnchors[1..<hostWithAnchors.count]
    let urlWithSeveralAnchors = hostWithPath + "#" + anchors.joined(separator: "%23")
            
    let url = URL(string: urlWithSeveralAnchors)
    // Continue working with the url
}
```