# stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding deprecated

Tags: objective-c

This is deprecated "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding", I want to replace this line with update one.

```
NSString *encodedString = [modalData.imageURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: NSString *str = ...; // some URL
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]; 
NSString *result = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacement for stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding in ios9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242712/replacement-for-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-in-ios9)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below line of code:

```
NSString *encodedString = [modalData.imageURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

**`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`**

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all
>   characters not in the specified set with percent encoded characters.

Character sets are passed to - `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`:

```
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLUserAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLHostAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPathAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet;
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSString *encodedString = [modalData.imageURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
NSString *url = [modalData.imageURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```