# URLWithString return null

Tags: objective-c, webview, nsurl, nsurlrequest

My code must update web view and download web site. But it doesn't because `URLWithString` returns null. How can I solve this problem? `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is already deprecated.

```
-(void) setWebViewMain:(NSString *) link {
    // link = @"http://www.rbc.ru/society/05/09/2017/59ae2dfe9a794753f05e3e06"; if this string uncomment code is working

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: link];

    NSLog(@"%@",url); // here url is (null)

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.webView reload];

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please improve you [question formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and clarify your question-

Comment: Clearly the value you pass in as `link` isn't a valid URL. You need to properly escape special characters.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529509/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-deprecated

Comment: Could you check: that `link` is really a NSString object? Could you check that it has correct no extra "{", or "("?

Comment: https://github.com/Vitalikspb/rss.git. 
link 100% NSString there is no "{", "("

Answer (score 0):

try as

```
  -(void) setWebViewMain:(NSString *) link {
// link = @"http://www.rbc.ru/society/05/09/2017/59ae2dfe9a794753f05e3e06"; if this string uncomment code is working

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",link]];

NSLog(@"%@",url); // here url is (null)

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
// [self.webView reload];
```

}

Answer (score -3):

Just remove the last line from your method and it will work:

```
-(void) setWebViewMain:(NSString *) link {
    // link = @"http://www.rbc.ru/society/05/09/2017/59ae2dfe9a794753f05e3e06"; if this string uncomment code is working

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: link];

    NSLog(@"%@",url); // here url is (null)

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    //[self.webView reload];
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
[self setWebViewMain:@"http://www.rbc.ru/society/05/09/2017/59ae2dfe9a794753f05e3e06"];
```

Comment: Please read the question (and the comment in the code you posted in your answer). The problem is that `url` is `nil`.