# Im getting the error, 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: objective-c

I have a issue that is popping up and it is 
    probably a syntax issue:

```
- (void)extracted_method:(NSString **)tempDir_p
{
  *tempDir_p = [*tempDir_p stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: 
  NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Im getting the error, 'stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0

Anyone?

Thanks
Paul

Ok I changed things abit and came up with this:

```
(tempDir_p *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: 
(NSASCIIStringEncoding *)  ;
```

still have the same error message...

btw, I am relatively new to this so I apologize if I am upsetting a few people here.  48 and back in school..

Comment: You need to pass in an NSCharacterSet instead of the encoding. See the link in my answer below for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for that method in the documentation, you will see this:

> Use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters: instead.

So adjust your code, and your warning will go away.

More info: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

`deprecated` is not a syntax issue; the compiler rather tells you that a particular message should not be used from a particular iOS-version on. For details, confer, for example, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32350410/2630032) (and upvote that answer if applicable).