# Implicit conversion of 'NSStringEncoding' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'NSCharacterSet * _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscharacterset

on following code i'm get the error message: Implicit conversion of 'NSStringEncoding' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'NSCharacterSet * _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC

Where i'm making wrong?

```
NSURL *candidatesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str_url
                                             stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong method. Instead of using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` use this `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

If you wan't to use this method `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` you have to pass a set of allowed characters.

Try this.

```
NSURL *candidatesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str_url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Or if you app development target is IOS 9.0 and above.

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated so you can use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` and use `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet`.

```
NSURL *candidatesURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[str_url stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: but when i use that method give the warning that this is deprecated method

Comment: This is deprecated. Check out this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242712/replacement-for-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-in-ios9

Comment: @BhumiNandola Yes it's deprecated but the `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` is available for IOS9 and above. See updated answer.