# ios URL(string: ) not working always

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl, url-encoding

```
let testurl = "http://akns-
images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018029/rs_1024x759-
180129200032-1024.lupita-nyongo-angela-bassett-black-panther-
premiere.ct.012918.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto"

if let url = URL(string: testurl){
    print("valid")
}else {
   print("invalid")
}
```

This prints as an invalid URL. But shows the image in web browser. I have seen lot of methods but it throws Apple warning to use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` and this doesn't work always.

I would prefer a solution to clean-up the url without encoding the complete urlstring. Encoding it at initial step can be a friction when passing to external libraries which will re-encode the url and make it invalid.

Comment: How to encode an url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url/43668198?s=1|59.9606#43668198

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242712/replacement-for-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-in-ios9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I have found my answer. Still will be checking for any side effects, comments are welcome:

```
let urlst = "http://akns-
images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018029/rs_1024x759-
180129200032-1024.lupita-nyongo-angela-bassett-black-panther-
premiere.ct.012918.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto"
extension String {
 func getCleanedURL() -> URL? {
    guard self.isEmpty == false else {
        return nil
    }
    if let url = URL(string: self) {
        return url
    } else {
        if let urlEscapedString = self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) , let escapedURL = URL(string: urlEscapedString){
            return escapedURL
        }
    }
    return nil
 }
}
```

This does not encode the complete URL but encodes only the invalid query characters (in eg url its '|'). Thus it can still be passed around as a string or a valid URL.

Comment: the cleanest way is to use URLComponents, as i mentioned in my answer...

Comment: Check my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 13):

Use `URLComponents`, it will handle escape characters automatically and encodes the url correct. no need to use `addingPercentEncoding`

```
func computeURL() {
    let testurlStr = "http://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/2018029/rs_1024x759-180129200032-1024.lupita-nyongo-angela-bassett-black-panther-premiere.ct.012918.jpg?fit=inside|900:auto"
    let components = transformURLString(testurlStr)

    if let url = components?.url {
        print("valid")
    } else {
        print("invalid")
    }
}

func transformURLString(_ string: String) -> URLComponents? {
    guard let urlPath = string.components(separatedBy: "?").first else {
        return nil
    }
    var components = URLComponents(string: urlPath)
    if let queryString = string.components(separatedBy: "?").last {
        components?.queryItems = []
        let queryItems = queryString.components(separatedBy: "&")
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            guard let itemName = queryItem.components(separatedBy: "=").first,
                  let itemValue = queryItem.components(separatedBy: "=").last else {
                    continue
            }
            components?.queryItems?.append(URLQueryItem(name: itemName, value: itemValue))
        }
    }
    return components!
}
```

Comment: for testurlStr you have hardcoded the value. How can this be generalised solution ?

Comment: I dont have query to prepare the url. I have got an external image url link with wrong characters which is valid in browser but invalid with the URL(string: testurl) method. I need to construct a valid URL from it without encoding complete url string.

Comment: i just took your code example as a starting point. If you have only the full string including host, path and query items, its easy to separat the parts... i've updated the example

Answer (score 11):

URL encoding is compulsory for building a URL from a string in case it contains special characters.

### Why we need URL encoding

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4668025/6073823):

> > A URI is represented as a sequence of characters, not as a sequence of octets. That is because URI might be "transported" by means that are not through a computer network, e.g., printed on paper, read over the radio, etc.
>
> And
>
> > For original character sequences that contain non-ASCII characters, however, the situation is more difficult. Internet protocols that transmit octet sequences intended to represent character sequences are expected to provide some way of identifying the charset used, if there might be more than one [RFC2277]. However, there is currently no provision within the generic URI syntax to accomplish this identification. An individual URI scheme may require a single charset, define a default charset, or provide a way to indicate the charset used.

In the IOS SDK we have the following:

User: `URLUserAllowedCharacterSet`
Password: `URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet`
Host: `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet`
Path: `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`
Fragment: `URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet`
Query: `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`

You can use `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` to encode a string correctly.

One important note according to [the apple docs for that method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding):

> Entire URL strings cannot be percent-encoded, because each URL component specifies a different set of allowed characters. For example, the query component of a URL allows the “@” character, but that character must be percent-encoded in the password component.
>
> UTF-8 encoding is used to determine the correct percent-encoded characters. Any characters in allowedCharacters outside of the 7-bit ASCII range are ignored.

An example:

```
let encodedURL = testurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
if let url = URL(string: finalUrl) {
    print("valid url")
} else {
    print("invalid url")
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer, I would even simplify it further by making it an extension of URL instead of String, that way we can still use an initialiser which is similar to URL(string:) with an identical output:

```
extension URL {
    init?(_ string: String) {
        guard string.isEmpty == false else {
            return nil
        }
        if let url = URL(string: string) {
            self = url
        } else if let urlEscapedString = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed),
                  let escapedURL = URL(string: urlEscapedString) {
            self = escapedURL
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please replace your line with:

```
let  finalUrl = testurl.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed)
if let url = URL(string: finalUrl){
    print("valid")
} else {
   print("invalid")
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy  Edited Have A look

Comment: `finalUrl` is an optional, so it can't be used in `URL(string: finalUrl)`.