# URL in diffrent Language, How to convert a URL in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My Image URL contains a Greek word. like URL [http://example.com/ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ.jpg](http://example.com/%CE%A5%CE%A0%CE%97%CE%A1%CE%95%CE%A3%CE%99%CE%95%CE%A3.jpg), URL class give me nil value

my code

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ.jpg"){
      //Image Download 
}
else{
     NSLog("invalidURL")
}
```

how can i create a URL Object to download this images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492592/4601900

You need to encode it Because your last path component is not looks like plain string

```
let testurl = "http://example.com/ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ.jpg"


if let  encodedURL = testurl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedURL) {
    print("valid url")

} else {
   print("invalid url ")
}
```

Ouptut

> valid url

If your print your `encodedURL` you will get  // Here if you print encoded url you will get 
 **http://example.com/%CE%A5%CE%A0%CE%97%CE%A1%CE%95%CE%A3%CE%99%CE%95%CE%A3.jpg**

Answer (score 2):

You have to encode your String to get a valid URL. You can do this by using `String.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: )`.

```
let urlString = "http://example.com/ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ.jpg"
guard let encodedString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedString) else {
      return
}
print(url)
```

The encoded URL becomes:

> http://example.com/%CE%A5%CE%A0%CE%97%CE%A1%CE%95%CE%A3%CE%99%CE%95%CE%A3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a UTF-8 readable format for the URL so for example

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΕΣ.jpg"){
```

would be

```
if let url = URL(string: "http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%CE%A5%CE%A0%CE%97%CE%A1%CE%95%CE%A3%CE%99%CE%95%CE%A3.jpg"){
```

You can use a a code/decode service like http://www.webatic.com/run/convert/url.php to convert these. Or, you can use a url shortner to provide a UTF-8 readable url.