# URLRequest can't process url with JSON object in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a url with stringified JSON object appended as below -

[http://localhost:53692/api/ccdata/UserWatchlist?userid=2&watchlist={\"Coin\":[\"BTC\",\"ETH\",\"LTC\",\"DASH\"]}](http://localhost:53692/api/ccdata/UserWatchlist?userid=2&watchlist=%7B%5C%22Coin%5C%22:[%5C%22BTC%5C%22,%5C%22ETH%5C%22,%5C%22LTC%5C%22,%5C%22DASH%5C%22]%7D)

Now my problem is `URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)` can't process this url and giving me nil error

What should I do?

Comment: you have to encode url with percentage then it will  be valid

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492592/4601900

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios URL(string: ) not working always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576329/ios-urlstring-not-working-always)

Comment: are you using `Alamofire` or `URL Session` ?
in alamofire you can do this `let Request: String = String.init(format:"http://localhost:53692/api/ccdata/UserWatchlist?userid=2&watchlist={\"Coin\":[\"BTC\",\"ETH\",\"LTC\",\"DASH\"]}")`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya your solution worked for me.Thanks.