# Url works in Postman but not in Swift app

Tags: swift, api, url, request

I have a url that works in Postman and in browser, but not in app.
I have an if let url = URL(string: urlString) line, but apparently the URL(string: urlString) is returning nil so it doesn't enter the block.  It doesn't actually throw an error so I can't actually search for an error.

I've tried looking at other people's similar problems but haven't found a solution.  Any help would be appreciated.  If you could point me to another post with a potential solution I'd appreciate that too.  Thank you.

Here is my code.  I've used this many times before with no problems.

```
func performRequest<T: Codable>(urlString: String, returnType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void ) {
      print("\n\(#function)")
      if let url = URL(string: urlString) { // <--- FAILS RIGHT HERE
         let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
               completion(.failure(error))
               return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
               let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
               completion(.success(decodedData))
            } catch let decodingErr {
               completion(.failure(decodingErr))
            }
         }
         task.resume()
      } else {
         print("Something went wrong with the url")
      }
   }
```

Comment: What's the actual value of `urlString`?

Comment: Post the `urlString`. It is most likely a formatting issue with you supply that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492609/6576315

Comment: @RTXGamer You should provide some description for what this link is for. E.g. is this a duplicate question? A similar solution? A general reference for how to do something? Etc, would be useful for some description.

Comment: what is the parameter `returnType: T.Type` for?  After `print("\n\(#function)")` could you put `print(urlString)` and show us what it prints.

Comment: @MadProgrammer my exact url is: https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/TimeZone/?key={MY-API-KEY}&query=tokyo, japan&output=JSON
It works perfectly fine in Postman and in any browser, but not in app.  I double checked the url is formatted correctly, and copy pasted the url from the app when I was stepping through it to make sure that exact url works in Postman and in browser.

Comment: remove the space between tokyo, and japan" like this  "...query=tokyo,japan&output=JSON"

Comment: @workingdog Thank you, that was the problem.  I guess Postman and browsers don't care if there's a space in the url, but Swift does.

Answer (score 0):

There was a space in my url that Swift wasn't accepting.  Apparently Postman and browsers can still make the call with a space, but not Swift.  Thank you to @workingdog for solving this.