# Swift: string url encoding not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, url

So I have a url like this:

```
let remoetURL = "http://xxx-test.img-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/materials/talk_-XXXXX-XXXXXXX/STEM RULE.pdf"
```

As you can see, at then end of the url, there is a white space, so I need to get rid of it to have a valid encoded url.

After doing some research, I realized I might use

```
let escapedString = remoteURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())
```

But this does not returned the expected working url, because it encodes the ":" after "http" too

```
http%3A//xiaobandeng-staging.img-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/talk_materials/talk_-K4yjX4-238Ku74WVIJk/STEM%20RULE.pdf
```

I have also tried URLHostAllowedCharacterSet, but no luck. So I wonder if it is because I don't have **www** here, so it does not recognise which part is the host correctly. If so, what might be the elegant solution? I know I could replace white spaces with %20 by calling stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString, but that seems just a bit fragile.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this used by **SwiftyJSON**

`let urlString = remoteURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())`

**Swift 3**:

`let urlString = remoteURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)`

Comment: This is the right answer. Previously, I was having some misunderstanding towards those `NSCharacterSet ` methods. For `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet `, I thought it only deals with the query part of a url, but it turned out to be dealing with the whole url conforming to a valid query format, which will parse spaces, but not slashes.

Comment: This is not really correct, for example this will escape the `#` anker (e.g. http://blub/index#hello). 
I suspect you have to first parse that invalid URL format coming in according to the rules you set, and then construct a proper URL from it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
let urlPath = NSString(format: remoetURL).stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

For `iOS 9`

```
let encodedHost = NSString(format: remoetURL).stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be the right answer. I actually saw this method before, but don't know why some said it is a deprecated method. But no warning for me, so I guess I should always try before I make a conclusion.

Comment: [stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015750/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-was-deprecated-in-9-0-how-to-do-this) was deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: @MidhunMP, hmm, but there is no warning for me. Then what should I use in this case? Any suggestion?

Comment: @Chenglu: What is your minimum targeted iOS version and the base sdk version ?

Comment: @MidhunMP, the targeted is 8.0, and the base is 9.3

Comment: @Chenglu: Can you check the answer linked in my first comment, whether it is working for you or not ?