# NSURL gives nil when Arabic words are passed through URL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried using `StringByAddingPercent` but get the same results as shown.

Here is the error message I am getting:
[image: Error message]

I have also tried string by adding percent, but it returns something like `%2A` and saves it in an SQL database instead of as Arabic words.

```
NSString* source = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/سُبْحَانَ اللّهِ/1000"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:source];
```

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil

Comment: Add percentencoding.

Comment: it gives me warning like... stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding was deprecated in ios 9.0....even that i have do it but it returns me %2 etc like and saves (??) into sql database

Comment: @Awais - for your updated querry see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015750/stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding-was-deprecated-in-9-0-how-to-do-this

Comment: Printing description of url:
http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/%D8%B3%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%91%D9%87%D9%90/1000

Comment: i have do it but the results are same...url gives....Printing description of url:
http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/%D8%B3%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%91%D9%87%D9%90/1000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URLWithString: returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981390/urlwithstring-returns-nil)

Comment: Fixed a lot of strange formatting, but not exactly sure what he's saying

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : [need you here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630350/touch-dont-respond-if-phone-in-locked-and-unlocked-again)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ...its done thanks for your help...it was done with UTF8stringEncoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *string = @"http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/سُبْحَانَ اللّهِ/1000";

NSLog(@"url with string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:string]);
NSLog(@"url with escaped string! %@", [NSURL URLWithString:
[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]);
```

Hope this helps you !

Update for decoding url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
              [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *myString = url.absoluteString; // or url.relativeString;

NSString* str = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Sir Thanks for help , but now kindly tell me how to decode it, e.g =   url with escaped string! http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/%D8%B3%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8E%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%91%D9%87%D9%90/1000,   Now what should i do, can i save that data in data base? or decode it and then save it, @siddheshMhatre

Comment: @Awais check for Update for decoding string

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/سُبْحَانَ اللّهِ/1000" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you. Swift version: self.url = "http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/سُبْحَانَ اللّهِ/1000".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version:

self.url = "[http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/سُبْحَانَ](http://192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/%D8%B3%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8E%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8E) اللّهِ/1000".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

Answer (score 0):

Below line will do the magic

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
    [source stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
];
```

You need to make encoding before making URL.

Comment: @Awais : don't post same link again and again... your path is `c:/` how come `c:` will open in iPhone?

Comment: how can i show/upload my screenshot to show u plzzz help

Comment: @Awais : [chck this](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=upload+png+files&oq=upload+png+files&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6636j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Sir Thanks for help , but now kindly tell me how to decode it, e.g = url with escaped string! 192.168.227.1/student/Service1.svc/insertTasbeeh/…, Now what should i do, can i save that data in data base? or decode it and then save it, @Fahim Parkar