# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' is deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a warning:

> /Users/pholahem/Documents/development/ohmycode_pro/ohmycode_pro/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m:92:40: 'CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes' is deprecated: Use [NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:] instead.

on Xcode for the following code:

```
static NSString * AFPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    static NSString * const kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey = @"[].";

    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}

static NSString * AFPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

I tried to read documentation on how to use the `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` way but I could not figure out how to rewrite the wrong code with the right function.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi all, Sorry I missed the traditional "Hello all" in the post. Thanks for any help on this as I am a newbie in iOS.

Comment: what's your problem here, actually the warning clearly stated that to use newest instead .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encode a URL in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879659/how-to-encode-a-url-in-swift)

Comment: What version of AFNetworking are you using?