# Swift - Construct URL with filter parameters

Tags: swift, url

I am trying to construct an URL with filter parameters, like so:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://myapi.com/api/customers?filter={\"where\":{\"name\":\"myName\"}}")
```

But this returns nil. Is there a way to have an URL object of this format? Or should I use another method to construct my request?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use URLComponents, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/24888789/1187415 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668198/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = URLComponents(string: "http://myapi.com/api/customer")!

url.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "filter", value: "{\"where\":{\"name\":\"myName\"}}")
]
```

Comment: That did the work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add percent encoding to the string if it doesn't starts with `http://`:

```
let string = "myapi.com/api/customers?filter={\"where\":{\"name\":\"myName\"}}"

let escaped = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

let url = URL(string: escaped)
```

Comment: That won't work because it will escape the `://` and `=` parts of the URL. You need to escape the parts first, then assemble them.

Comment: That worked too, thanks! Though I think I should still use URLComponents as it's its purpose?

Comment: @M.Garrigues yes, that is the recommended way of adding query items