# change string to valid url swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

hi I want to receive image from a source but I realized it has some characters that swift Urlsession return nil on the I want to know how can I change this url

> https://melovaz.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/¡Viva-Latino-2.jpg

to

> https://melovaz.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/%C2%A1Viva-Latino-2.jpg

using swift so I can download the image thank you

Comment: I tried actually but no - that did not fix the problem

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, this is what I get if I use the answer from that question in a playground: `https://melovaz.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/%C2%A1Viva-Latino-2.jpg`

Comment: yes thank you it worked . I was passing raw string to URLSession. thank you

Answer (score 0):

thank to this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879659/how-to-encode-a-url-in-swift)

I should use

```
var urlString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```