# How to convert string with spaces to NSURL

Tags: swift, macos, nsurl

```
Run below code in playground

import UIKit
let serverUrl = "smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test/untitled folder"
let sharePath = NSURL(string: serverUrl)
```

sharePath value is returning nil

How to handle this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encode a URL in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879659/how-to-encode-a-url-in-swift)

Comment: Normally you don't. Your string is not a valid URL and once you have it, it cannot be safely converted to a valid URL because you don't know which parts are not correctly encoded. You might just replace any space with a `+` char but there might be other problematic characters.
To safely create a URL (or a URL string) you have to encode every part separately. In this case you might take everything after the last `/` and encode it as a path component, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let serverUrlStr = "smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test/untitled folder"
guard let formattedUrl = serverUrlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else { return }
let sharePath = NSURL(string: formattedUrl)
```

> Note that it's not generic.
> Read comments for more context.

Comment: Your solution will work for this specific URL, it's very bad as a generic solution.

Comment: Yes, I know. Other `CharacterSet` can handle other cases.

Comment: The allowed characters are not used the way you think they are. Actually, there is rarely a reason to use them at all. They definitely won't help with URL encoding.
For example, `urlQueryAllowed` contains `?` and `&` which are *allowed* in a query but they must be encoded if they are present in a query parameter.
Nevertheless, you cannot just blindly use percentage-encoding to the whole URL, every component must be encoded separately.

Comment: Can you please give an example of cases that won't work? Is all this is doing internally is `strWithSpace.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")`? Exactly what we see when we paste a URL with space on the browser tab. It might not be a working URL but the structure is right.

Comment: Well, one simple example is trying to encode an URL, that is actually valid (and properly encoded), e.g. `smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test/untitled%20folder` or if you try to encode an unencoded character that is actually valid to appear in query but not in query value, e.g. a `+`, full example: `smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test?phone=+2001234` - the `+` will be kept unencoded.
In summary, URL encoding is context sensitive. You cannot safely encode the whole URL - you have to encode every component separately and you have to know whether it has been already encoded or not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Well, I tested two of your test cases. `smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test/untitled%20folder` gets converted to `smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home/test/untitled%2520folder` which is faulty. And it is far from generic.

Comment: How do I know if it is already encoded or not? Should I check if it contains space or '/` or others? But for `smb://example.net/Data/OS/Home%20Folder/test/untitled folder` it has partial encoding in `Home%20Folder` and no encoding in `untitled folder`. Is other no other way than encoding every part separately for a generic solution?